# vba index small if with multiple criterias

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing an issue when trying to compile a multiple criteria Index/Match code in `VBA`. I want to create a macro for this example, The formula is working perfectly but I want a `VBA` code. I have a range from `G2` to `G10`.
Could anyone help me? Thanks

```
Sub y()
Range("H2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:C4,SMALL(IF(C4=RC7,ROW(C4)),COLUMNS(RC8:RC)),1),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H2:H3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:R3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H2:R3").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

For use in VBA following conventional programming syntax for a Sub and related Declarations, Use the following line for using Array Formula in VBA.

```
'Change Sheetz and Range("xx1:xx10") as per your requirement
Sheetz.Range("xx1:xx10").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$D,SMALL(IF($D:$D=$G2,ROW($D:$D)),COLUMNS($H2:H2)),1),"""")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
Sub Match()

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 7).Value Then
           Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
Else
       Cells(i, 8).Value = ""

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

However, you should definitely try to write some code first before posting next time because it's important that you try it yourself before coming for assistance!! But hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I have this code but is not as fast as yours, and my trouble is trying to compile a multiple criteria so I need to help. Thanks

Sub y()

    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:C4,SMALL(IF(C4=RC7,ROW(C4)),COLUMNS(RC8:RC)),1),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H2:H3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:R3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H2:R3").Select
End Sub